# Active Record join for class in module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 6/ Ruby 2.7

So I have two classes `ModuleX::SubModuleA::Order` and `ModuleY::SubModuleB::OrderType`

and I want to do something like

`ModuleX::SubModuleA::Order.joins("ModuleY::SubModuleB::OrderType")...`

This syntax would be pretty simple normally:  `ModuleX::SubModuleA::Order.joins(:order_type)` but I cannot find any documentation regarding how this works for classes in modules.

Comment: The syntax you show should work if you are defining your relationships properly in your models.  The relationship definition, eg. `belongs_to` or `has_one`, is where the module names/scopes come into play.  Show us your real code instead of the hypothetical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of `joins` allows two uses: first, referencing a relation defined on the left-hand model by its (symbolic) name, or second, raw SQL. Neither method is actually impacted at all by the use of modules, because neither references the *class* of the model you're joining onto.

In your case, you probably want to set up a relation between orders and order types, like:

```rb
class ModuleX::SubModuleA::Order
  belongs_to :order_type, class_name: 'ModuleY::SubModuleB::OrderType'
end
```

Then, you can just do the same syntax as you expect:

```rb
ModuleX::SubModuleA::Order.joins(:order_type).all
```

Comment: Thank you, this was pretty obvious in retrospect